# Annotation value in advice

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to access my annotation values in advice, my annotation can be placed on type or method.
so far i am able to get the annotation value when applied on method but no success when the annotation is applied on type.

```
@Before( value = "(@annotation(varun.mis.aspect.Logged) || within(@varun.mis.aspect.Logged *)) && (@annotation(logged))",argNames = "logged" )
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can get the annotation as an argument when applied to a type

The following pointcut expression

```
@Before("@annotation(com.some.TestAnnotation) || within(@com.some.TestAnnotation *)")
```

will match either a method annotated or a class annotated. You can then declare the advice to get the annotation either from the method or from the class

```
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
TestAnnotation annotation = methodSignature.getMethod().getAnnotation(TestAnnotation.class);
if (annotation == null) {
    Class<?> clazz = methodSignature.getDeclaringType();
    annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(TestAnnotation.class);
    if (annotation == null) {
        System.out.println("impossible");
    } else {
        System.out.println("class has it");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("method has it");
}
```

You should also consider the case where both the method and the type have the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try as follows using annotation directly: add `com.mycompany.MyAnnotation yourAnnotation` in your `advice params` and `@annotation(yourAnnotation)` in `@Around`.

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(yourAnnotation)")
public Object procede(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, com.mycompany.MyAnnotation yourAnnotation) {
    ...
    yourAnnotation.value(); // get your annotation value directly;
    ...
}
```

`com.mycompany.MyAnnotation` in advice params just work as that in

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)")
```

`yourAnnotation` can be valid variable name since `MyAnnotation` in params already points out which annotation it should be. Here `yourAnnotation` is used to retrieve the annotation instance only.

If you want to pass more params you can try `args()`.